# Php upload error"Not Found The requested URL /Programs/lo.jpg was not found on this server."

Tags: php

I have created this code but I am facing an error when I click on view file it says.

> Not Found The requested URL /Programs/lo.jpg was not found on this server.

```
 <!Doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>try</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="fileuploadtry.php" method="post">
    Browser for file to Upload:<br>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="80"> <br>
        <input type="submit" id="u_button" name="u_button" value="Upload the file ">
        <br>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>

    //uploadfile.php

    <?php
    if($_FILES['file']['name'] !="")
      copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"c:/wamp64/tmp".$_FILES['file']['name']);
      else die("no file specified");
    ?>
    <!Doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>File upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
        <li>Sent:<?php echo $_FILES['file']['name'];?></li>
         <li>Sent:<?php echo $_FILES['file']['size'];?></li>
         <li>Sent:<?php echo $_FILES['file']['type'];?></li>  
            <a href="<?php echo $_FILES['file']['name']; ?>">click here toview file</a>
        </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Write the embedded php code using isset() the php code is executed before the user selects the file to be uploaded.

Comment: Stop keeping the html form and the processing code in the same file. That makes absolutely no sense. Yes, I know that many tutorials show exactly that, but that does not change a thing. It only gives you trouble. Place separate things in separate files. One file holding the form your client loads and uses, one file / endpoint uses for retrieval of the asset or whatever else.

Comment: you mean php code in seprate folder and html form code in seprate folder